# Need trigger on Update Condition

Tags: apex, trigger

I wrote a trigger for insert condition. there are some fields 
(Key Negotiator,Partner in Charge and Project Design Leader which is contact lookup field) in opportunity object.When I select contact record on lookup in these field,then insert contact role related to opportunity. But getting a problem in update condition. how to do it?

Trigger:

```
trigger CreateContactRole on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {

    List<OpportunityContactRole> newContactRoleList=new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
    List<OpportunityContactRole> oldContactRoleList=new List<OpportunityContactRole>();

    Set<Id> OppId=new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> ContactId=new Set<Id>();


    for(Opportunity oppObj: Trigger.new)
    {
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
    if(oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c !=null && (oppObj.Services_Offered__c != Null || oppObj.Project_Name__c != null || oppObj.Account != Null || oppObj.StageName !=Null
       || oppObj.CurrencyIsoCode != Null || oppObj.Name != Null || oppObj.CloseDate != Null || oppObj.Referred_By__c != Null || oppObj.Design_Offices__c !=Null))
    {
        newContactRoleList.add
        (
        new OpportunityContactRole (
        ContactId=oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c,
        OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, 
        Role='Key Negotiator')
        );
     }

     if(oppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c !=null && (oppObj.Services_Offered__c != Null || oppObj.Project_Name__c != null || oppObj.Account != Null || oppObj.StageName !=Null
       || oppObj.CurrencyIsoCode != Null || oppObj.Name != Null || oppObj.CloseDate != Null || oppObj.Referred_By__c != Null || oppObj.Design_Offices__c !=Null))
     {
        newContactRoleList.add
        (
        new OpportunityContactRole (
        ContactId=oppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c,
        OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, 
        Role='Partner in Charge')
        );
     }

     if(oppObj.Project_Design_Leader__c !=null && (oppObj.Services_Offered__c != Null || oppObj.Project_Name__c != null || oppObj.Account != Null || oppObj.StageName !=Null
       || oppObj.CurrencyIsoCode != Null || oppObj.Name != Null || oppObj.CloseDate != Null || oppObj.Referred_By__c != Null))
     {
        newContactRoleList.add
        (
        new OpportunityContactRole (
        ContactId=oppObj.Project_Design_Leader__c,
        OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, 
        Role='Project Design Leader')
        );
     }
    }
    else{
      if(oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c ==null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Key_Negotiator__c !=null)
            {

                 Opportunity OldoppObj=Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id);        
                 OppId.add(OldoppObj.id);
                 ContactId.add(OldoppObj.Key_Negotiator__c);

            }
            else if(oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Key_Negotiator__c==null)
            {

                newContactRoleList.add(new OpportunityContactRole (ContactId=oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c, OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, Role='Key Negotiator',IsPrimary=True));
            }
    }
    }

    if(newContactRoleList.size()>=0 || newContactRoleList.size()!=null){   
        system.debug('--newContactRoleList-->>'+newContactRoleList);
    insert newContactRoleList;

    if ( OppId.size()>0) oldContactRoleList=[Select Id from OpportunityContactRole where ContactId in : ContactId  and OpportunityId in : OppId];

    if (oldContactRoleList.size()>0) 

    Update oldContactRoleList;
      system.debug('--oldContactRoleList-->>'+oldContactRoleList);
    }


}
```

It's working only insert condition but i want update condition too.

Comment: your trigger only fires after insert - see line 1

Comment: Updated my trigger.

Comment: Remove the "if(Trigger.isInsert){" statement and see what happens

Comment: this trigger should be refactored to use a helper class and in that class you can have methods to mask the complexity of the various compound if conditions. You can also add debug statements to figure out why your after update produces no list to update. You also don't need to test for empty list before doing the `insert newContactRoleList` - SFDC will do nothing and not consume a DML statement if list is empty; same for the `update oldContactRoleList`. Bottom line, a refactored helper class w debug statements will be of great use. Read up on trigger patterns

Comment: When I remove if(Trigger.isInsert) and insert new records then create 2 contact roles. Means here both condition fire at same time.